# How to point github pages to custom html home page

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have started using GutHub-Pages. I am using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and my `gh-pages` repository has the following structure:

```
gh-pages (repo)
+-site
| +-about.md
| +-_config.yml
| +-index.html
+-notes.md
```

I would like to have `htts://<username>.github.io/<repo>` point to `site/index.html`.

How to do this? Thanks

Comment: I searched for this once, there are lots of resources out there. Here's one: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have `htts://<username>.github.io/<repo>` point to site/index.html.

You can write a simple html which redirect to the desired page

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/site/index.html">
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/ for directions on how to make any github page redirect to another page.

If you want a viewer to see the index.html hosted on github pages when they visit `site/index.html`, you'll need to talk to whoever owns the DNS for `site`.

Answer (score 0):

In `/site.index.html` set `permalink: /` in the front matter.